# How could the test_and_set() instruction still work on a multiprocessor?

Tags: operating-system, critical-section, instructions

Dear stack overflow community,
I'm reading Operating System Concepts (2012) by Silberschatz, Galvin and Gagne, it says "if two test_and_set() instructions are executed simultaneously (each on a different CPU), they will be executed sequentially in some arbitrary order." on page 210, I cannot understand why two such institutions will be executed **sequentially** even on a multiprocessor. What if each instruction is executed on a different processor? To the best of my knowledge, these two institutions be executed **simultaneously**.  
My understanding of the atomicity of instructions and the multiprocessor stays at a quite superficial level, so I may take the problem for granted. Could anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The whole point of test-and-set is that one processor will execute it first, and then the other processor will execute it, and they will *not* do it simultaneously.

To achieve this, there will be some communication between both processors. Basically, one processor will load the cache line including the memory location from memory, and tell the other processor that it can't have that cache line until both test and set are finished.

Answer (score 2):

The outcome depends upon the machine instruction. Let me use the VAX as an example as it is an easy to understand processor:

http://www.ece.lsu.edu/ee4720/doc/vax.pdf

The VAX has a BBSS (Branch on Bit Set and Set) instruction and a BBSSI (Branch on Bit Set and Set Interlocked) instruction.

If you have 2 processors doing a BBSS on the same clear bit you could get:

```
P1 Tests Bit (Clear)
P2 Tests Bit (Clear) 
P1 Sets Bit and does not branch
P2 Sets Bit and dot not branch
```

If you do a BBSSI on the same bit, the processor locks the memory. You get

```
p1 locks the memory
p1 Tests Bit (Clear)    
P2 Tests Bit and is Blocked
P1 Sets Bit and does not branch
p1 unlocks the memory
P2 Tests Bit (SET)
P2 Branches
```

Instructions do not execute in a single step for the most part and the processors can operate independently of each other.

Comment: Thank you! Really excellent answer and material! I've read the explanation of the BBSSI from the link. I'm a little bit confused with "If the bit is contained in memory, the reading of the state of the bit and the setting of the bit to the new state is an interlocked operation", does it implies that the bit to be tested and set can be contained in memory or in register of processor? If it's contained in one register, then we don't need to interlock the bit but how BBSSI is used by a programmer since the bit is in the register?

Comment: The VAX has an orthogonal instruction set, meaning it allows any addressing mode for any operand (except for move address of memory using registers). Thus, you could use a BBSSI instruction with a register operand. In that case the execution is not interlocked and acts like a BBSS instruction. It really would not make a lot of sense.